# Python speech to text using speechrecognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am making a software which uses speech to text. I have read some article and post on stackoverflow. I tried this code-

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print("Speak:")
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize_google(audio)+';')
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
```

After I run the code when it reaches this part it makes the input phase and stops. It does nothing and tkinter window Doesn't respond. It looks like this.[image]

I tried both `r.recognize_google` and `r.recognize_sphinx`. I also tried not using microphone index. I can't understand what is happenning. When it comes to `r.listen(source)` it stops. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [code](https://github.com/dawntcherian/Google-speech-to-text-python-websocket-server-using-microphone-stream) in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
audio=r.listen(source)
```

To

```
audio=r.record(source, duration=4)
```

You can change the value of duration.

Let me know if it works :)